# URL Rewrite Redirect doesn't quite work

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

I am using URL Rewrite Rules in my WEB.CONFIG. I have the site set up in IIS. Just a very quick and simple site.

This is how my Web.config looks like.

```
<rule name="CTVNews Articles" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*?)CTVNews(/?)(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ctvnews.ca{R:2}{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

This is the entry in my default.aspx page that i want to redirect

a href="http://www.ctv.ca/CTVNews/TopStories/20110106/domtar-investment-110106">Click here to redirect

So, nothing fancy. But The redirect just doesnt work. And I think my entry in the web.config is correct.

Do I need to set up the host file at all for this?